# Trying to drop and recreate indexes in my 'Refresh' stored procedure, but getting an error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to drop/recreate indexes and refresh a MV daily using the below stored procedure. However i am getting a compilation error. Also, (might be off topic) for most Materialized View refresh jobs, what else would be considered as 'good practice' to include? Thanks in advance!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "DAILY_MV_REFRESH" AS
BEGIN
  --Drop Index(es)
drop bitmap index mv_test_id;
  --Refresh the Materialized View(s)
dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST');
  --Recreate Index(es)
create bitmap index mv_test_id on mv_test(test_id);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute DDL directly in a PL/SQL procedure; it has to be in an `execute immediate` statement.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "DAILY_MV_REFRESH" AS
BEGIN
  --Drop Index(es)
  execute immediate 'drop bitmap index mv_test_id';
  --Refresh the Materialized View(s)
  dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST');
  --Recreate Index(es)
  execute immediate 'create bitmap index mv_test_id on mv_test(test_id)';
END;
/
```